# If result of the LINQ has an interface type it means it has a deferred execution

Tags: c#, linq

Working with LINQ i found that when result of the LINQ expression has an interface type it means that it has a deferred execution. Am I right?

**For example:**

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// Deferred execution because res1 has an IEnumerable<int> type
var res1 = numbers.Where(x => x > 2);

// Immediate execution because res2 has an int[] type
var res2 = numbers.Where(x => x > 2).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's more "Immediate execution because you are calling `ToArray`". `IEnumerable<int> res3 = numbers.ToArray()` would be executed immediately

Comment: There are good chances that this rough assumption is true but it's mostly an implementation detail. Do not take it for granted. If, for example, `ToList()` returned `IList<T>`  then you still have an interface but it's not deferred. It does not even make it always sense, think about `Empty<T>()`, for example.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter give me an examples, please

Comment: @HelloWorld: i gave

Comment: Technically even `var res2 = numbers.Where(x => x > 2).ToArray();` uses deferred execution, but it doesn't *really* matter, since it is only deferred from the `From` call, to the `ToArray` call.  Deferred execution can actually take place anywhere that an `Expression`, or `Delegate` is used.

Comment: I would suggest you read about [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not correct, even the array implements `IEnumerable<int>`. You don't know from the type if it's using deferred execution since there is no `IDeferred` interface.

I think the best what you could do is to try to cast it to `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection`:

```
public static bool IsDeferred<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    ICollection<T> genCollection = source as ICollection<T>;
    if (genCollection != null) return false;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

```
var arr = new int[5];
bool deferred = arr.IsDeferred(); // false
IEnumerable<int> seq = arr.Where(i => i != 0);
deferred = seq.IsDeferred();      // true
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not right

If you have an IQueryable, that will create an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` which gives you deferred execution. What you have is an expression.

If you have an IEnumerable, which could be a list, an array or anything else. Or it could even be a function that returns IEnumerable, you end up with a `Func<T, bool>` which is executed as soon as you access it.

This can be bit of a trap, if you have something like this

```
private IEnumerable<Test> GetTests()
{ 
   return _context.Set<Test>();  
}
```

and you did

```
var tests = GetTests().Take(100);
```

You actually have a `Func<T, bool>` here. You will take all records from db and then just do that `Take(100)` in memory.

If you do

```
var tests = GetTests().AsQueryable().Take(100);
```

now you have an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` with deferred execution. the `Take(100)` will happen on Db server

Or you could return IQueryable in the first place and not IEnumerable. I am just trying to show the difference between the 2.

Comment: "You actually have a Func<T, bool>", where?

Comment: The tests variable will be `Func<Test, bool>` and when you do the Take(100) it will execute a full select on the server then do Take in memory. That because an IEnumerable was used and not an iQueryable

Comment: In your example, `tests` is an `IEnumerable<Test>`

Comment: Up until you do `.Take(100)` it is not materialised. It is still a `Func<T, bool>` that is yet to execute against the server. When you do `Take()` it executes and you get your Enumerable. the gotcha is it selects everything and then does the Take because you didnt have an expression.

Comment: Even after calling Take(100) it is not materialized. If `tests` was a `Func<T, bool>` you wouldn't be able to call `Take` on it since `Take` takes an `IEnumerable<TSource>` in parameter

Comment: But you returned it as an IEnumerable, accessing tests causes it to materialise. Mock it up in VS and see for yourself.

Comment: Not necessarily, `Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Skip(2).Take(3)` does not materialize the range for instance. It would if you added `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` for instance.